# E: Unable to locate package kali-linux-wireless

Tags: wireless-networking, kali-linux

I cannot use wifi on Kali linux.

Here is the list of packages listed which does not seem to include the wireless package:

```
root@localhost:/abhinav# apt-cache search kali-linux
kali-linux-arm - Kali Linux ARM system
kali-linux-core - Kali Linux base system
kali-linux-default - Kali Linux default system
kali-linux-everything - Everything in Kali Linux
kali-linux-headless - Kali Linux default headless system
kali-linux-large - Kali Linux large system
kali-linux-nethunter - Kali Linux NetHunter tools
kali-linux - Transitional package for kali-linux-core
```

How can I fix it so that I can use the wifi?

Comment: You need a driver for your computer that is compatible with Kali.  It does not have a driver database for all possible wireless connections.

Comment: What is your wifi network adapter?

Comment: This could be as a result of missing wireless adapter.
Add the output from `lspci` to your question.